# TypeScript 3: property is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript3.0

I'm working on a ReactJS app with TypeScript. I was using TypeScript 2.8 with no problem, but 2.9 and 3 give me a new error.

```
import * as React from 'react';


class ExampleComponent extends React.Component<{}, {
        firstName: string, lastName: string
    }> {
    clearState() {
        this.setState({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: ""
        });
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName: '', lastName: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
       //***** This is the line that gives me an error ******
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });

    }
    public render() {

        return <form>

            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <label className="sr-only">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control name-element" id="firstName"
                            placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} required={true} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <label className="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control name-element" id="lastName"
                            placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} required={true} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    }
}

// Wire up the React component to the Redux store
export default ExampleComponent;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; } | ((prevState: Readonly<{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }>, props: {}) => { firstName: string; lastName: string; } | Pick<{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }, "firstName" | "lastName">) | Pick<...>'.
  Type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }, "firstName" | "lastName">'.
    Property 'firstName' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: any; }'.
```

I think that the type system wants a guarantee that the value passed will be a valid one (ie "firstName" or "lastName"). I'm not sure about what construct to apply (and how to apply it) to appese the compiler. I think I need to extract an interface and use it in two places: where I define the state in the component, and somewhere in the handleChange method.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your state is defined, in typescript yes, as a `Record` with keys `firstname` and `lastname`. When `event.target.id` is a wider type `string`, although in your case it's recognised as `number` for some reason.

One way would be to cast it to `any` like (UPDATED):

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value } as any);
}
```

In this case I suppose it wouldn't matter much, because there is no typesafety in this statement from the beginning

Comment: None of these seems to work unfortunately. All three give the same compilation error.

Comment: ```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value } as any);
  }
```

Comment: That did it! Can you fix your answer and I'll upvote and mark correct? (I was not the person who downvoted)

Comment: Thanks! I'd suggest you remove the last two suggestions also, since they seemed both not to work for me.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent the entire day looking for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think to get a more reliable type check you could add a handler for each input like this

```
function makeHandler(
    id: WhatEnumYourIdIs
): (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void {
    return function(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void{
        this.setState({ id: target.value });
    }
}
```

Then to add a handler

```
<input onChange={this.makeHandler(Enum.FirstName)} />
```

If you rely on the input id you cannot guarantee that the state field will match, it may compile but it won't actually be type checking.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is in my actual code, instead of two fields, I have eight. It feels not great to essentially have eight method handlers doing the same thing, where I only needed one  until the newer TypeScript. I'm hoping there's some way to appease the compiler while keeping only one function.

Comment: In that case usually for something like this I would curry the first argument, if you want to use the real power of typescript you want to make sure you are type checking everything you can, using an any type should be a last resort and should rarely be necessary. I'll update my example with an example